trigger a function at a given point with time.periodic flutter
hello i have a code that count from 0 minutes to ten minutes using the timestamp so that all my users will see the same time at the same moment and it works well,but when we reach 15 minutes i want to trigger a function but it doesn't work and i don't know where i am wrong
clock() {//don't really worry about the calculations 
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (clock) {
     var timesUp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
     var timesupSeconds = (timesUp / 1000).floor();
     var minutes = ((timesUp % (1000 * 60 * 15)) / (1000 * 60)).floor();
     var seconds = ((timesUp % (1000 * 60)) / 1000).floor();

     if ((timesupSeconds % (15 * 60)) == 0) //When it is true it means we are at 15 minutes
     {
         print('it is 15 minutes');// this is where i want to trigger the function and it doesn't //work
     }

     setState(() {
         time = '$minutes m: $seconds';
     });


You need to ensure that the function triggers at the 15-minute mark and doesn’t get skipped, you can add a flag to detect if the function has already been triggered. For example:
bool hasTriggered = false;

 clock() {
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (clock) {
    var timesUp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    var timesupSeconds = (timesUp / 1000).floor();
    var minutes = ((timesUp % (1000 * 60 * 15)) / (1000 * 60)).floor();
    var seconds = ((timesUp % (1000 * 60)) / 1000).floor();


    if ((timesupSeconds % (15 * 60)) == 0 && !hasTriggered) {
      hasTriggered = true; 
    } else if ((timesupSeconds % (15 * 60)) != 0) {
      hasTriggered = false;
    }

    setState(() {
      time = '$minutes m: $seconds';
    });
  });
}


YEEEEEEEEEEEES It WOOOOORKS thank you so much again, you can't imagine how you helped me
